# Why is "no matching overload found" error appearing even though I have them defined

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, auto

Going through some template tutorial I encountered the following error:

> Error (active)    E0304   no instance of overloaded function "sum" matches the argument list  Templates

I know that I am dealing with variadic templates here but I cannot see why the overload for multiple parameters is not being detected. Also worth mentioning that the exact code in the tutorial I am following does not throw any error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;



typedef complex<double> cd;




// specialization for when there is only one argument
template <typename T>
T sum(T t) { return t; }

// -> defines a return type as a result of sum values
template<typename T, typename ...U>
auto sum(T t, U ...u) -> decltype(t + sum(u...))
{
    return t + sum(u...);
}


void variadic()
{ 
    cout << sum(1, 2, 3, 4) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    //consuming_templates();
    //template_functions();
    variadic();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2672    'sum': no matching overloaded function found   Templates

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2893    Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type sum(T,U...)'  Templates   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2780    'T sum(T)': expects 1 arguments - 4 provided   Templates   C:\Users\erind\source\repos\Templates\Templates\Templates.cpp   35
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question, and mark out the lines in the code you show (with e.g. comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a works for `std::common_type`.

I mean... try rewriting your `sum()` variadic version as follows

```
template<typename T, typename ...U>
auto sum(T t, U ...u) -> typename std::common_type<T, U...>::type
{
    return t + sum(u...);
}
```

The problem in your code is that with

```
template<typename T, typename ...U>
auto sum(T t, U ...u) -> decltype(t + sum(u...))
{
    return t + sum(u...);
}
```

you try to set the return type recursively with `decltype(t + sum(u...))` but doesn't works.

Starting from C++14, you can simply use `auto`, without trailing return type

```
template<typename T, typename ...U>
auto sum(T t, U ...u)
{
    return t + sum(u...);
}
```

Starting from C++17, you can use template folding and avoid recursion at all

```
template <typename ... U>
auto sum (U ... u)
 { return (u + ...); }
```